# How to install aclocal in ubuntu14.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, package, ubuntu-14.04

I want to install aclocal -I m4 in ubuntu 14.04 when i run the command its showing

[image: Unable to locate package aclocal]

First installed

`sudo apt-get install autotools-dev`

then,

`sudo apt-get install aclocal`

same error also getting.

Answer (score 0):

Install it from source, you avoid a lot of troubles compiling other software in the future. `aclocal` package does NOT exist, and is part of `automake` package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install automake
```

Will install `aclocal`
I recommend compiling from script, it will update to the latest version

```
#!/bin/bash
VERSION=1.15
    wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz &> /dev/null
    if [ -f "automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz" ]; then
            tar -xzf automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz
            cd automake-${VERSION}/
            ./configure
            make && make install
            echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[1;32mOK\e[39m   ] automake-${VERSION} installed\e[0;39m"

        else
            echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[31mError\e[39m   ] cannot fetch file from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/ \e[0;39m"
            exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install all of the following packages to get `aclocal` running:

```
apt install automake
apt install autoconf
apt install m4
apt install perl
apt install libtool
```

---

This was the error message that I received when I tried to install ssdeep:

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.13' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
Makefile:426: recipe for target 'aclocal.m4' failed
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
/bin/sh: 1: libtoolize: not found
/usr/bin/m4:aclocal.m4:1069: cannot open `m4/libtool.m4': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/m4:aclocal.m4:1070: cannot open `m4/ltoptions.m4': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/m4:aclocal.m4:1071: cannot open `m4/ltsugar.m4': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/m4:aclocal.m4:1072: cannot open `m4/ltversion.m4': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/m4:aclocal.m4:1073: cannot open `m4/lt~obsolete.m4': No such file or directory
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
automake: error: autoconf failed with exit status: 1
Failed while building ssdeep lib with configure and make.
Retry with autoreconf ...
Failed to reconfigure the project build.
```